# Draw vertically using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Consider the following drawing of a glucose molecule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[atom sep = 2em]{C(-[2]OH)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]OH)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]OH)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]OH)-C(-[2]OH)(-[6]H)-C(=[1.2]O)(-[6.8]H)}

\end{document}
```

[image: glucose]

How do I draw the molecule vertically instead of horizontally? (I hope the question makes sense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is possible, and it is easy. Just place the atoms above or below, instead of on the left or right

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{C(=[:150]O)(-[:30]H)-[6]C(-[4]HO)(-[0]H)-[6]C(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)-[6]C(-[4]HO)(-[0]H)-[6]C(-[4]HO)(-[0]H)-[6]C(-[4]HO)(-[0]H)(-[6]H)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In section 11.3 of the Chemfig manual there are several ways to draw the glucose molecule, including the Fisher projection. [mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf)

Comment: In section 11.3 of the Chemfig manual there are several ways to draw the glucose molecule, including the Fisher projection.    http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf